# Generating a route without having Lat/Lon coordinates

Tags: here-api

It seems that the Routing API requires a Lat/Lon pair to be supplied to the Waypoint parameter.  I've seen other APIs that allow for the actual address to be passed, instead of the Lat/Lon.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this with the Here.com API.  In many instances I can obtain the Lat/Lon first, but in one instance it's proving to be a headache, especially given the nature of the way that the REST APIs work and the fact that I'm trying to batch-process a small group of addresses at a single time.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Routing API needs a waypoint in lat, lon and required a Geocoding as a pre-requisite.

Maybe a not so nice workaround if you are facing issues with Geocoding, the Duck Duck Go provides a syntax

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!here Junghofstraße 14,60311 Frankfurt am Main,Germany, Germany&ia=about

But you will stll have to extract the lat,lon from the final redirected url.